# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler". Unity plugin

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, classnotfoundexception

App crashing on testers devices, but not on mine. I trying install appmetrica plugin, but it isn't work, stats of appmetrica console is null and this error, placing above.

I can't find the solution of this error. Can you please give the permanent solution. I have no idea how to solve it can you help me. Thanks sorry of my english.

```
    1 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    in: dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
    Tjava.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]Unity version     : 4.7.2f1
    Device model: samsung SM-T116Device fingerprint: samsung/goyave3gxx/goyave3g:4.4.4/KTU84P/T116XXU0AQA2:user/release-keysCaused 
    by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler" 
    on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/coloring.book.app-1.apk"],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/coloring.book.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2648)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:166)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)    
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    Didn't find class "com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler" 
    on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/coloring.book.app-1.apk"],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/coloring.book.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)   
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)    
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)    
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2643)  ... 10 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="coloring.book.app" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name="com.neatplug.u3d.plugins.common.NPUnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="sensor">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 844957685613468" />
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.neatplug.u3d.plugins.facebook.FriendPickerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="com.neatplug.u3d.plugins.facebook.LeaderboardActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <receiver
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
  android:exported="true"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

    <category android:name="com.yandex.mobile.metricapush.pluginunity"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
  android:name="com.yandex.metrica.push.core.notification.MetricaPushBroadcastReceiver"
  android:exported="false" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.push.action.NOTIFICATION_ACTION"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
  android:name="com.yandex.metrica.push.gcm.MetricaInstanceIDListenerService"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service> 
<service
  android:name="com.yandex.metrica.push.PushService"
  android:exported="false">
</service> 

<meta-data android:name="ymp_gcm_project_number" android:value="number:gcm_number"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

 <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> 


    <!-- AppMetrica Services and Receivers -->
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService" android:process=":Metrica">
      <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService"/>
        <data android:scheme="metrica"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="metrica:api:level" android:value="52"/>
    </service>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give more information about the devices on which that crash occurs (model, OS version)? It seems like a problem could be related with obfuscation or multi-dex.